# I want to return 'Alert' box if someone submits empty form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, computer-science, web-development-server

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus id="todotext" 
        type="text">
        <input onclick="serve(); return false" type="submit">
    </form>

    <ol id="add"></ol>

</body>

<script>
    function serve(){
        const neww = document.getElementById('add');
        let text = document.getElementById('todotext').value;
        const a = document.createElement('li');
        a.innerText = text;
        neww.appendChild(a);
        document.getElementById('todotext').value = "";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

**Here is my code and I want to return an 'Alert' if someone submit empty form.
How should I do it ?** Any help will be appreciated

*Here's an image:*

[image: This is the Image, Click here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus id="todotext" 
        type="text">
        <button onclick="todotext.value != '' ? serve() : alert('Input field is blank')" >Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ol id="add"></ol>

</body>

<script>
    var todotext = document.getElementById('todotext');
    function serve() {
        const neww = document.getElementById('add');
        let text = todotext.value;
        const a = document.createElement('li');
        a.innerText = text;
        neww.appendChild(a);
        document.getElementById('todotext').value = "";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 String.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    return (this.length === 0 || !this.trim());
};
 
 function serve(){
        const neww = document.getElementById('add')
        let text = document.getElementById('todotext').value;
        if( text.isEmpty() ){
            alert('cannot be blank');
          return;
        }
        const a = document.createElement('li')
        a.innerText = text
        neww.appendChild(a)
        document.getElementById('todotext').value = ""
    }
```

```html
<h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus id="todotext" 
        type="text">
        <input onclick="serve(); return false" type="submit">
    </form>
    <ol id="add"></ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

add condition when append new element by checking the value of todoText

```
   function serve(){
   const neww = document.getElementById('add')
   let text = document.getElementById('todotext').value
   if(text == ""){
       alert('field is required');
   }
   else{
     const a = document.createElement('li')
     a.innerText = text
     neww.appendChild(a)
     document.getElementById('todotext').value = ""
   };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function serve(){
        const neww = document.getElementById('add')
        let text = document.getElementById('todotext').value
        if(text.trim().length === 0){
          alert("Field is empty");
        }else{
        const a = document.createElement('li')
        a.innerText = text
        neww.appendChild(a)
        document.getElementById('todotext').value = ""
        }
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form>
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus id="todotext" 
        type="text">
        <input onclick="serve(); return false" type="submit">
    </form>
    <ol id="add"></ol>

</body>
</html>
```